# Cannot install Windows SDK for Windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows, winapi, sdk, installation

I try to install Windows SDK on a Windows 7 laptop because its a dependency of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) node.js module. (All Windows Versions.  For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will also need the Windows 7 64-bit SDK)

I went [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), hit Download, and got an `winsdk_web.exe` file. Run it and everything was going fine, until the last step, where I got "Installation failed".

This is what I get in the end

[image]

I copy/pasted the link from the above screen that got me to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2009/02/12/troubleshooting-windows-sdk-server-2008-download-install.aspx) page , so I can troubleshoot it, but I cannot find a `SDKSetupLog.txt` file anywhere. There is an SDK in the laptop in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A` , but frankly I dont know if it was already there before the installation or it created by it. The laptop is not mine.

My last log is:

> Last log : 2:03:10 πμ Sunday, 20 December 2015: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Windows SDK Setup (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack: in SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent) in SDKSetup.Product.SetupProduct(TaskMode taskMode, ManualResetEvent CancelEvent) in SDKSetup.ProductCollection.SetupProducts(TaskMode taskMode, DownloadManager downloadManager, ManualResetEvent cancelEvent) σε SDKSetup.ConfigProducts.DoCurrentTask(TaskMode Task)

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/slevin/84y8rbby/1/) fiddle to see the full log. 
Thanks

Comment: Always a good idea to uninstall any previous SDK installations before installing a new one. Installing the most recent version [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) is also not a bad idea. You can use the Windows 10 SDK on Windows 7 and target Windows 7.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. Yes, but I need to install a node.js module and it suggests that I should have a windows 7 sdk , see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) (All Windows Versions.
For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will also need the Windows 7 64-bit SDK). Also, when I check my Programs on Control Panel I cannot find a windows sdk, except Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK and Microsoft Silverlight 5 SDK.

Comment: What happened when you clicked "View Log"?

Comment: @andlabs A SDKSetup_7.0.6918.0.log txt file opens.

Comment: @andlabs Last log : `2:03:10 πμ Sunday, 20 December 2015: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Windows SDK Setup (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack:    in SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)    in SDKSetup.Product.SetupProduct(TaskMode taskMode, ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)`

Comment: @andlabs ....and continues `in SDKSetup.ProductCollection.SetupProducts(TaskMode taskMode, DownloadManager downloadManager, ManualResetEvent cancelEvent)    σε SDKSetup.ConfigProducts.DoCurrentTask(TaskMode Task)`

Comment: You should post the contents of the file in your question instead of posting it in the comments; it'll be easier to process (and you'll be able to post the full thing). Judging from that paste alone, however, did you somehow accidentally cancel it?

Comment: @andlabs No, I get to the last step and I get "Installation failed". When I click the View Log button this is the info I get.